# VBA in Word code to delete or change code from ThisDocument

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code in a Microsoft Word .docm file that disables the save function and pops up a message:

```
Sub FileSave()
MsgBox "Save is Disabled." & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "To save changes, use Save As."
End Sub
```

This might be tricky but what I want to do now is disable *that* code, that is, to enable saving again, on a certain trigger event (when a user clicks a button).

When the document is first opened I have it so only save as is enabled, not save. After a certain event, I want save to work again.

I've gotten things like this to work, to programmatically ***add*** code to ThisDocument:

```
 ThisDocument.VBProject.VBCompontents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString "Private Sub Document_Close(): ActiveDocument.Saved = True: End Sub"
```

However I don't know if there is a way to edit or delete code, using other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way would be to have a variable of type Boolean. When the button is clicked change the value of the Boolean, and then use a conditional statement to re-enable saving

Comment: Yep, I had come up with something sort of similar before coming back and seeing this. Since there's something that the button deletes anyway, I can just make the conditional statement look for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work a different way, making the code that disables save an If statement:

```
Sub FileSave()
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("table") = True Then
    MsgBox "Save is Disabled." & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "To save changes, use Save As and overwrite your file."

Else:
If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then ActiveDocument.Save
End If

End Sub
```

It looks for a bookmark that gets deleted on the button click event, and if it exists then save is blocked. Once the bookmark has been deleted, users can save again.

I'd still be curious to know how to delete code if anyone knows but this is a simpler approach I guess.